# Render multiple dicts in muliple tabs for a flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I want to render multiple dicts json to front.
All in the same interface.
But each one in a specific tab.
And the tabs have to be created dynamically based on the number of dicts.
A basic example

```
[{"name" = a, "age" = 29},{"name" = b, "age" = 19}, {"name" = c, "age" = 28}]
```

The first tab will be a table containing the first dict {"name" = a, "age" = 29}, the second tab a table containing {"name" = b, "age" = 19} and so one.
Knowing that I don't now the length of json in advance

Comment: What do you mean by tab in this case. Be more specific with your question.  And please tell what you have tried, you should read the [question asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear but from what I understood, you can do something like this:

```
{% for tab in my_tab_list %}
<tab> Name: {tab.name} Age: {tab.age} </tab>
{% endfor %}
```